# Invalid Read on closed Body on Google App Engine

Tags: http, google-app-engine, go

When submitting a POST to a Go web app on Google App Engine, I receive a 500 error. In the GAE logs, the error is:

`http: invalid Read on closed Body`

The handler in the web app streams from the `*http.Request.Body` reader, and writes incrementally to `http.ResponseWriter`.

The `Body` reader is being closed unexpectedly, before being completely read. Why would this happen?

Answer (score 10):

By design, the HTTP/1.x server in Go closes the `*http.Request.Body` after the first flush of the `http.ResponseWriter`. See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/15527) for the explanation.

Concurrently reading and writing is fine in theory — it’s unspecified from a standards perspective — but Go does not handle it. If code begins writing to the Response before the Body is completely consumed, there is a good chance that the Body will be closed unexpectedly.

To avoid this, you might:

- Write into a `bytes.Buffer` instead of directly into `http.ResponseWriter`. After you are sure the Body is completely read, you can write the buffer into the response all at once, e.g. using [bytes.Buffer.WriteTo](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.WriteTo) or perhaps [io.Copy](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy). Here’s [an example](https://github.com/clipperhouse/jargon/blob/master/web/main.go#L61).
- Or, you can use [ioutil.ReadAll](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll) to read the whole body, before any writes.

(In both of the above cases, there may be a bit more memory pressure than you desire, since either the incoming or outgoing bytes are gathered in memory instead of streamed, but it appears unavoidable.)

(This behavior is not particular to App Engine.)